# Disjoint equivalence classes of a set of matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, equivalence-relations

Let $M$ be the set of $m \times n$ real matrices. Consider the following equivalence relation: $A, B$ are equivalent if there exists a real invertible $m\times m$ matrix $P$ and a real invertible $n \times n$ matrix $Q$ such that $A=PBQ$. Find out into how many disjoint equivalence classes if $M$ partitioned by this equivalence relation.

---

I know that in case of square matrices, two similar matrices have same rank. Is the given problem somehow related with rank? Please help in solving this problem.

Comment: Yes, it's related to rank. Show that the equivalence classes are precisely the matrices of a fixed rank.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Well, just try it. What do you know about what you can do to a matrix by left and right multiplication by invertible matrices? (As a second hint: this includes all invertible row and column operations.)